# Input design validation issue in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to reproduce that validation.

[image]

This is what I achieved yet:

[image]

I am missing that triangle from the bottom. I want to use css/css3 to solve this. This is what I tried, but without succes:

```
.contact-form .parsley-errors-list .parsley-required:after{
padding: 8px;
background-color:red
margin-top: 1px;
transition: none 0s ease 0s;
position: absolute;
content: "";
left: -6px;
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Can you guide me How do I achieve that triangle with css/css3 ? thx

Comment: yes, nothing special, just do it from jquery and other things like that. nothing related to css3 to develop that triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this and see if it helps

```
.contact-form .parsley-errors-list .parsley-required{
    position: relative;
}

.contact-form .parsley-errors-list .parsley-required:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 10px;
    border-left: 10px solid red;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: perfect . Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
.arrow_box {
position: relative;
background: #FF0000;
}

.arrow_box:after {
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
border: solid transparent;
content: " ";

height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
border-top-color: #FF0000;
border-width: 15px;
margin-left: -15px;
}
```

For a "straight" arrow.

```
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 20px 20px 0 0;
border-color: #ff0000 transparent transparent transparent;
```

This lets you create it using borders.